# how can I run multi wallet on one computer to share same blockdata

Tags: database, datadir

you know ,you need a 32GB size for one bitcoin client,is it possible to run several bitcoin programs sharing same data source using -datadir or something else? I have found that somebody had put it  about a year ago and got an big NO; Since 1 year has passed ,is it still NO?

Comment: "Run several bitcoin programs" is a bit vague. What are you intending to do exactly? Maybe you are overthingking the problem, or you have misunderstood something. What is the reason for having "multi-wallet"? What do you want to acheieve and why?

Comment: Try to add a link to the other question that you mentioned.

Comment: @T9b  bitcoin programs mean bitcoin-qt.exe ;this is the situation, I have ten wallets running as server while each has about 20000 addresses. I can run them in different harddrives ,which will cost me at least 350 GB's harddrives' money.But if I import these wallet into one ,the bitcoin-qt.exe will be incrediblely slow to do the "rescanning" .

Comment: As I suspected, you are going about this completely the wrong way. Why on earth did you choose Bitcoin QT to manage this? Again not enough information on your part, I guess you are running some kind of e-commerce site, in which case you would do very well to look at Hierarchical deterministic wallets or even an SPV client like the original Multibit would do. They have a Beta HD version too: https://github.com/bitcoin-solutions/multibit-hd I suppose also you could look at Bitpay too.

Comment: @T9b  yes, its an e-emmerce site.Now im going to see what multibit-hd is like,thanks for your information.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows it wouldn't work because of file locking/sharing I suspect and on Linux that wouldn't be a problem but the data would surely get corrupted. There's no advantage to running multiple servers either, if you need to process more transactions than the server can handle then you should probably be doing it a different way or with multiple machines. If it's to help the network then one will do - leave it 24/7 and it will start to provide more than 8 connections if you allow it via config.

Comment: I can do this on Linux?How? It wont't bother me if the wallet file collapse for the next use ,it helps even works for just one time

Comment: it's the block chain data that I think would get corrupted.

Comment: ok,im going to find another way